# Using foreign key in controllers Laravel 9

Tags: laravel-9

I was creating two tables user and user_info and i want to use the userid in userinfo.
I don't know how to use the userid in userinfocontroller.

Comment: You can start by reading the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `one to one` relation in your models.
in `User` Model :

```
    public function info()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(Info::class,'foreign key'); // (Info = your userinfo model)
    }
```

and in your `Info` model :

```
    public function user()
    {
          return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign key');
    }
```

you can read [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) too.

Answer (score 0):

In the User Model

```
public function info()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(userinfo::class); 

    }
```

And in userinfo Model

```
public function user()
    {
          return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
'user_id'
    }
```